# HttpUrlConnection method is always GET on android

Tags: java, android, http

```
URL url = new URL("http://myserver.com/myendpoint");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
//connection.setRequestMethod("POST") <- this didn't help either
connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write("string=test");
out.close();
connection.close()
```

**The code above WORKS on desktop JVM**, sends a post request, parsed on server-side successfully with response 200, however on android, the request method stays GET (yes I checked it IS false) and results in a 404 exception. Official docs say that setting doOutput to true triggers setting the request method to POST but that doesn't seem the case.

Comment: have you given internet permission? 404 means page not foune! may be path wrong

Comment: yes internet permission is granted to the app

Comment: 404 doesn't relate to GET or POST. It relates to URL only.

Comment: `connection.setRequestMethod("POST");`

Comment: @Gaurav please read my code again, that one DID NOT HELP

Comment: @ÁbrahámEndre If you are able to modify the server-side code, please specify the whole server-side code.

Comment: @ÁbrahámEndre Besides, do some debug stuffs on your server, check clearly whether is the connection is GET. And is the parameter is sent to the server. Though you said the code above works on desktop, I always debug with both code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

404 is not an exception. It is a HTTP status code returned by the server you make the request to and it means that the url you make the request to is not found. That has nothing to do with POST being set or not.

Things to check:

- If the url you are making a request to is right.
- If the server has a POST controller/handler mapped to the url you are making the request to.
- Ask the guy who develops the server if he is handling the cases right ans if he's sending the correct response codes for the relevant scenarios.

Extra info: if the url is registered on the service but a POST request is not allowed you would get a 415 response code.

Comment: I'm not stupid I know what 404 is but java drops a FileNotFound exception on 404. And again, **the same code works on desktop** so there is **no problem with my server**

Comment: @ÁbrahámEndre Tim Castelijns is answering this cause you wrote "404 exception" in your answer. No one is insulting you that you are stupid.

Comment: @ÁbrahámEndre check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605624/adnroid-httpurlconnection-filenotfoundexception-connect-to-http-and-pass-params or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354305/android-http-url-connection-throwing-file-not-found-exception-at-getinputstream, the FileNotFound exception is thrown because the outputfilestream cannot be instantiated because of the 404

Comment: Indeed, the exception was thrown because of an error 400 not because of a 404! :)

Answer (score 1):

When posting data to a server, I'm setting some additional request header:

```
String query = "string=test";
URL url = new URL("http://myserver.com/myendpoint");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(query.getBytes("UTF-8").length);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(query);
```

But as suggested, the 404 exception usually means, that the endpoint, you're trying to access, isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```js
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```